# grass algorithms no longer run in QGIS/Sextante

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, sextante

I used to be able to run GRASS algorithms in QGIS 2.0 via Sextante (Ubuntu 12.04) but not anymore. Initially I would double click on any grass algorithm and the execution would stop with:

"WELCOME TO GRASS              Version 6.4.3         2013

1. Have at your side all available GRASS tutorials
2. When working on your location, the following materials
   are extremely useful:

   - A topo map of your area
   - Current catalog of available computer maps
3. Check the GRASS webpages for feedback mailinglists and more:
   #I removed url because my reputation is below 10 and that doesnt allow to post more than 2 links

Hit RETURN to continue"

But after rebooting, if I double click on any grass algorithm, QGIS just hangs there. The same algorithm then works as expected in GRASS GIS 6.4.3 and via QGIS/GRASS plugin.

I've already completely removed and reinstalled (sudo apt-get purge qgis* and sudo apt-get purge grass*) QGIS and GRASS and removed ~/.qgis2 and ~/.config/QGIS

GRASS GIS is apparently working ok. When I double click on the icon, the command line launches with:

WELCOME TO GRASS              Version 6.4.3         2013

1. Have at your side all available GRASS tutorials
2. When working on your location, the following materials
   are extremely useful:

   - A topo map of your area
   - Current catalog of available computer maps
3. Check the GRASS webpages for feedback mailinglists and more:
   http://www.grass-gis.org
   http://grass.osgeo.org

Hit RETURN to continue

It's most likely a local problem but at the moment I'm out of ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try launch GRASS with

```
grass --wxpython
```

Comment: Thanks, typing grass wx--python solved it. It appears that something on my system changed the way GRASS was launched and caused that "Welcome message" to appear and block the connection between Sextante and GRASS. Typing that set things right. EDIT: It seems that my reputation is not high enough to vote up your answer.

Comment: This should be reported as a bug to QGIS...